# Semantic HTML markup for links to sections of current page in headers

Tags: html, nav, semantic-markup

I've written markup for a header with links to different pages and also sections of the current pages and I wanted to know the following:

Are the tag names I used semantically appropriate?
Is the structure/hierarchy correct?
Does my markup need to be optimized/changed for easy CSS styling?

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Section 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

I want this markup to be as standardized as possible and also being ready to be styled in any possible way without the need to go back to the markup and change it.

Comment: Note that asking for SEO advice is off-topic here. You can ask what markup would be semantic based on the HTML spec, but not whether or not search engines make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nav` element represents the navigation for the section it’s in:

- For the site-wide navigation, the `nav` should be in the `body` sectioning root element (because this represents the whole page).
- For a table of contents (like in an Wikipedia article), the `nav` should be in the `section`/`article` sectioning content element which represents the content the ToC is for.

(Example 9 in [the `nav` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-nav-element) shows exactly this case.)

So, you would ideally use something like this (assuming it’s some kind of article):

```html
<body>

<h1>Site title</h1>

<nav>
  <!-- the nav for the site-wide navigation -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h2>Article title</h2>

  <nav>
    <!-- the nav for the article -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</article>

</body>
```

(Each section can have its own `header`, so you could place the first `nav` in the `body`-`header` and the second `nav` in the `article`-`header`, if you want.)

Comment: Wouldn't that become a problem when using CSS to place them both on the header? I'm thinking about having a row of large links to different pages of my website and right below it another row with smaller links which scroll to different sections on the current page and both rows are thought to be on a fixed header.

Comment: @S.Goody: Yes, sometimes it’s not possible to use the ideal HTML because of CSS restrictions. It depends, of course -- so it might be possible in your case. You could ask a separate question about it, showing the HTML you want to use and the layout you would want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

i would say SEO related... Meta Tags we called it.

The logo image it should be  - **alt** tag is important. 
Example your website is "Basketball forum" related.. you can put inside that alt="" like this **alt="Basketball forum Logo"** then try to all images in your website, you have to write an alt tag keywords related page/topic.

then the  Element - you have to write a title on it, so people or Search engine can see where the link is heading.

Example:

```html
<a href="/basketball_player_names" title="Basketball Player Names">link</a>
```

SEO is really really huge. More info folow the link below.. its from google
https://developers.google.com/search/

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely important to us the alt tag (though I knew this much), but I was more hoping to learn about node/element structures and tag names.

Seems I wasn't descriptive enough with my questions. sorry.

Comment: there is also what we called Rich Snippet  a search engine technology that could help to define more your website content, that is the link above :) its fun to learn..